# How can python function actually change the parameter rather than the formal parameter?

Tags: python, function, syntax

I am trying to code "1024" using python basic library. In the process I try to make a list [0, 2, 4, 4] become [0, 2, 8, 0]. So here is my test code. It's very easy one.

```
    def merger(a, b):
        if a == b:
        a += b
        b = 0


    numlist = [0, 2, 4, 4]
    merger(numlist[0], numlist[1])
    merger(numlist[1], numlist[2])
    merger(numlist[2], numlist[3])
    print (numlist)
```

So when I try to conduct merge. I expected the output [0, 2, 8, 0]. However it gives me [0, 2, 4, 4] instead. I think maybe it's because I just changed the local variable of my function a b rather than the actual parameter? But If I want this to happen, what should I do? Thx!

I think I want to know generally if I want a function not return anything but just change value of the variable I passed as parameter. How can I achieve it?

Comment: You can introduce global variables with `global a, b`. However, this is generally not considered good practice... One usually prefers to get values from functions using the `return` statement.

Comment: @nostradamus: Yes, it's good to avoid modifying globals, but `global` won't help with the OP's code.

Comment: Oh that's interesting. Thx!

Comment: In my opinion, one can do pretty much everything with global variables, it's just the exact opposite of elegant coding... For example, you could introduce 4 global variables here: `numlist = [g1, g2, g3, g4]` and a local variable named `gsender`. The latter would carry the information to `def merger(gsender)`, which two variables should be merged. Not elegant at all, but you feasible.

Comment: I assume maybe it's more like the safety reason. Using global variable may cause some insecurity or instability of the code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pass the list and indexes to the function:

```
def merger(l, a, b):
    if l[a] == l[b]:
        l[a] += l[b]
        l[b] = 0

numlist = [0, 2, 4, 4]
merger(numlist, 0, 1)
merger(numlist, 1, 2)
merger(numlist, 2, 3)
print(numlist)
```

As list object will be passed by reference and any changes on the list inside the function will be effective after the function call.

Comment: Learned a lot! Thx!