# Why I use list as a parameter of a function and the function can't change the value of the actual parameter but only the formal parameter?

Tags: python, function, python-3.x

It's the similar question with this one I asked (Visit [How can python function actually change the parameter rather than the formal parameter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39160682/how-can-python-function-actually-change-the-parameter-rather-than-the-formal-par?noredirect=1#comment65665408_39160682) ), Only this time I am using list to be formal parameter. So because list is reference type? It should worked as before.
So here is my code:

```
def twomerger(lx, ly):
    if lx[0] == ly[0]:
        lx[0] = ly[0]
        ly[0] = 0
    if lx[1] == ly[1]:
        lx[1] = ly[1]
        ly[1] = 0
    if lx[2] == ly[2]:
        lx[2] = ly[2]
        ly[2] = 0
    if lx[3] == ly[3]:
        lx[3] = ly[3]
        ly[3] = 0


row1 = [0, 2, 4, 4]
row2 = [2, 2, 4, 4]
twomerger(row1, row2)
print (row1)
print (row2)
print ("it's a new situation:")
print (row1)
print (row2)
```

Here I try to transfer [0, 2, 4, 4] and [2, 2, 4, 4] into [0, 4, 8, 8] and [2, 0, 0, 0]. (make the same vertical number adds up). I passed two list -- row1 and row2 into the parameter of my function `twomerger`. I thought because row1 and row2 is list, they are reference so this function should be able to change the row1 and row2. However it gives me the result `[0, 2, 4, 4]` and `[2, 2, 4, 4]` which means the function doesn't work. So I am confused again.

Comment: It's a bad practice anyways to let functions modify variables directly. You're better off returning lx and ly.

Comment: @u8y7541,  there is nothing wrong with a function modifying lists once that is what it is supposed to do. I would not want to create two new lists just to change/modify a few elements

Comment: Is it a bug/typo that you print the same thing twice, with only the words "its a new situation" in between them?  It doesn't change whether the test works, but that is always going to print the same thing twice - you want the first one before `twomerger()` call.

Comment: Yes you are right @GreenAsJade, it's a bug, I noticed now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think your issue is that you should be adding to the values in the list, but instead you're reassigning. Change `=` to `+=`:

```
def twomerger(lx, ly):
    if lx[0] == ly[0]:
        lx[0] += ly[0]
        ly[0] = 0
    if lx[1] == ly[1]:
        lx[1] += ly[1]
        ly[1] = 0
    if lx[2] == ly[2]:
        lx[2] += ly[2]
        ly[2] = 0
    if lx[3] == ly[3]:
        lx[3] += ly[3]
        ly[3] = 0

row1 = [0, 2, 4, 4]
row2 = [2, 2, 4, 4]
twomerger(row1, row2)
print (row1)
print (row2)
```

**Output**:

```
[0, 4, 8, 8]
[2, 0, 0, 0]
```

For what it's worth, your method can be written much more concisely:

```
def twomerger(lx, ly):
    for i, num in enumerate(lx):
        if lx[i] == ly[i]:
            lx[i] += ly[i]
            ly[i] = 0
```

Or if you're comfortable with [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#zip):

```
def twomerger(lx, ly):
    for i, (a, b) in enumerate(zip(lx, ly)):
        if a == b:
            lx[i] += b
            ly[i] = 0
```

Comment: You can avoid multiple indexing using zip  `for i, (a, b) in enumerate(zip(lx, ly)): if a == b...`

Comment: Sure - I've added a note. I tend to err on the side of newbie-friendly when it comes to these types of questions, but it's good to list more options for future users too :)

Comment: True, but generally using zip for element wise comparison would be the  idiomatic approach.

Comment: Agree! Still trying to figure out the balance between idiomatic vs. understandable to the OP when answering. Thanks for reminding me that it's probably best to include both.

Comment: No worries, you did not need to add anything bar the first part of your answer but since you added enumerate I thought you may as well go all out with zip ;)

Comment: Is it wierd that there is a compromise between idiomatic and understandable.  Why wouldn't we all chose understandable every time, and that would become the idiom?

Comment: Oh yes it is! Sorry now I think it's a dumb question haha... Your code is much more beautiful than mine. I will learn from that slowly. Thx!

Comment: @Karin Hi so I try to understand the first code you write here. I don't know what's the variable num for? because I don't see "num" involved in the code.

Comment: @TonyChen `num` is the variable that is assigned to each element of the list as you loop through it.